# Download file using angular - other character encoding in db and html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I saving data in database(sql server) using Latin1. My html application uses utf-8 encoding.

Server side is wrote in c# using WebApi.

When I try to download file from db which contains word ' 123' in txt file:

```
$http.get<string>(url).success(data=> console.log(data);
```

I get this: �123
After use this

```
unescape(encodeURIComponent('�123'));
```

I get "ï¿½123"

How can to convert returned string from server to proper one ?

Comment: need to fix at server